# Inserting a single backslash into a string or list python

Tags: python, arrays, byte

I have a bytes object

> b"'\x91\x84\xa4\x74\x69\x6d\x65\x93\xcb\x42\x2b\x5b\x8b\xb7\x00\x00\x00\xcb\x42\x2b\x5b\x8b\xb7\x00\x05\x1f\xcb\x42\x2b\x5b\x8b\xb7\x00\x0a\x3e\xa4\x76\x61\x72\x30\x93\xcb\x40\x24\x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\xcb\x40\x24\x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\xcb\x40\x24\x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\xa4\x76\x61\x72\x31\x93\xcb\xff\xf8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcb\x40\x34\x19\x99\x99\x99\x99\x9a\xcb\x40\x34\x19\x99\x99\x99\x99\x9a\xa4\x76\x61\x72\x32\x93\xcb\xff\xf8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcb\xff\xf8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcb\x40\x3e\x19\x99\x99\x99\x99\x9a'"

I want to replace the `\\` to `\` for further processing to pandas msgpack library. I tried replacing in so many ways and couldn’t find the answer though the same problem was mentioned in many posts.

I had converted it into a string:

> 'x91x84xa4x74x69x6dx65x93xcbx42x2bx5bx8bxb7x00x00x00xcbx42x2bx5bx8bxb7x00x05x1fxcbx42x2bx5bx8bxb7x00x0ax3exa4x76x61x72x30x93xcbx40x24x33x33x33x33x33x33xcbx40x24x33x33x33x33x33x33xcbx40x24x33x33x33x33x33x33xa4x76x61x72x31x93xcbxffxf8x00x00x00x00x00x00xcbx40x34x19x99x99x99x99x9axcbx40x34x19x99x99x99x99x9axa4x76x61x72x32x93xcbxffxf8x00x00x00x00x00x00xcbxffxf8x00x00x00x00x00x00xcbx40x3ex19x99x99x99x99x9a'

I can insert `“/”` but then it cannot be processed in msgpack. When I try to insert `“\”`, I get double backslashes again. Could anyone please help me with this?

**My desired output is:**

> b'\x91\x84\xa4\x74\x69\x6d\x65\x93\xcb\x42\x2b\x5b\x8b\xb7\x00\x00\x00\xcb\x42\x2b\x5b\x8b\xb7\x00\x05\x1f\xcb\x42\x2b\x5b\x8b\xb7\x00\x0a\x3e\xa4\x76\x61\x72\x30\x93\xcb\x40\x24\x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\xcb\x40\x24\x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\xcb\x40\x24\x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\xa4\x76\x61\x72\x31\x93\xcb\xff\xf8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcb\x40\x34\x19\x99\x99\x99\x99\x9a\xcb\x40\x34\x19\x99\x99\x99\x99\x9a\xa4\x76\x61\x72\x32\x93\xcb\xff\xf8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcb\xff\xf8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcb\x40\x3e\x19\x99\x99\x99\x99\x9a'

Comment: when you say "converted it into a string", do you mean a literal in your source code?  downvote wasn't me, but maybe due to lack of formatting or length of examples. a couple of bytes would be fine for understanding this

Comment: 1. Formatting 2. Code you tried;  may be the reasons..although I have not downvoted it!!

Comment: Your bytes object and desired output looks same!!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I meant a variable of class "str". Sorry for the incorrect formatting.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal When I print I get the desired output with single backslash. In the variable it is stored with double backslashes. But the msgpack function needs the input with single backslash.Otherwise I get different outputs

Comment: Suppose, if have two inputs : x and y      x=b'/x91/x84/xa4/x74.........' and y=b'\x91\x84\xa4\x74......' when I give these two inputs to pandas.read_msgpack(), I get different outputs say p for x and q for y.   p=[47, 120, 57, 49, 47, 120, 5.....] and q = ({'time': (58750000000.0, 58750000000.01, 58750000000.020004), 'var0': (10.1, 10.1, 10.1), 'var1': (nan, 20.1, 20.1), 'var2': (nan, nan, 30.1)},). I need this q output. That is the reason I am forced to have a single backslash in my input.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
x = '/x91/x84/xa4/x74'
b = x.replace(r'/', '\\')
```

Now just don't wirte `b` in your console it will show you as double `\\`. If you want to see `b` as it is intended write `print(b)`

Comment: But I cannot then store the output I get using print(b) to pass to another function right?

Comment: Thank you for your comment :)

Comment: don't need to print that...`b` has a value exactly what you want...just pass `b` to another function. The `print` information was just to tell you the value that `b` contains is right

Comment: I understand that \\ is python representation of escape sequence \. But I dont get the desired output with msgpack when I pass b.

Comment: It still gives you output as `p` and not `q` as per your above comment

Comment: Yes thats right..what I need is q unfortunately. I am stuck at this portion since two days because of the double slash issue